# How to run a web server within Angular App

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, capacitor

I'm working with angular along with Nodejs to build a native app with capacitorjs and I'm trying to build a web server within the app itself. I test the app on a localhost server but it needs to run one separate from that, Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

import * as http from 'http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
      $('#HelpBtn').click(function() {
      $('#Info').fadeToggle()
    })
  }

  btnClick() {
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
      res.end(); //end the response
    }).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
  }
}
```

Its running along with capacitor.js, so is there any builtin components or modules in either framework that can help me out? preferably one that can render .html files? somthing like [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-server/)

Comment: Angular executes within the browser on the client. I don't think you can create a back end web server within it.

Comment: ionic has a similar component (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-server/) like this

Comment: `This plugin allows you to start a local dynamic content web server for android and iOS devices.` Are you building a native app? Or a Web app?

Comment: I'm building a native app for android using capasitor.js (https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/) along with angular.

Comment: Consider adding that to your question so you get better answers.